# Ansible install npm package name from source binary (.tgz)

Tags: node.js, ansible

I need to install npm using ansible. I am Referring to Ansible 2.3 : http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/npm_module.html

I have packed npm module using `npm pack coffee-script` and have `coffee-script.tgz`. now I want to install it using npm by using that file.

The closest thing I can find is :

```
- name: Install "coffee-script" node.js package from custom registry.
  npm:
    name: coffee-script
    registry: 'http://registry.mysite.com'
```

But how to install from local file because my server doesn't have internet connection, hence I need to pack and install from the binary file.

I want to do something like this

```
- name: Install "coffee-script" node.js package from custom registry.
      npm:
        name: coffee-script
        global : yes
        source: '/usr/local/coffee-script.tgz'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox) which solve my problem perfectly.

from my machine I run command `npmbox coffee-script` which give me `coffee-script.npmbox`

then I paste to my offline server and run `npmunbox -g coffee-script.npmbox`

But you need to install npmunbox on your offline server too.

1. run : `npmbox npmbox` on your online machine
2. paste `npmbox.npmbox` it to offline server
3. run : `tar --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions -xvzf npmbox.npmbox` (or using `unarhieve` command in ansible)
4. run : `npm install --global --cache ./.npmbox.cache --optional --cache-min 99999999999 --shrinkwrap false npmbox`
5. now you can install any npm package offline using `npmunbox <package_name>.npmbox` (for example : `npmunbox pm2.npmbox` or `npmunbox coffee-script.npmbox`

Answer (score 1):

Please use this:

```
- name: Install "coffee-script" node.js package from custom registry.
  npm: 
    name: /usr/local/coffee-script.tgz
    path: /app/location
    global: yes
```

Comment: do we need to put `path` and `global` in the same command? isn't `path` is where we store nodeJS package ?

Comment: it's not necessary, but for best practices we put into same dir as app.

Comment: doesn't work, still loading from registry `[    ..............] - fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge`

Answer (score 0):

You can user module npm for offline installation.

```
- name: Install node.js package from custom registry.
  npm:
    name: "/tmp/pm2-3.5.1.tgz"
    global: yes
```

---

For multiple installation you can use `loop`.

Sample tasks:

```
- name: Find all tgz files in temporary directory
  find:
    paths: "{{ tmp_node.path }}"
    patterns: "*.tgz"
  register: node_files

- set_fact:
    node_list: "{{ node_files.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

- name: Install node.js package from custom registry.
  npm:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    global: yes
  loop: "{{ node_list | flatten(1) }}"
```

Where `node_list` it's list of .tgz npm packages placed in role in directory `files`.